# Curly brackets after trigonometric functions

Tags: math-mode

Is it necessary to insert curly brackets after a trigonometric function, like so?

`\sin{2x+1}`

or should one do it like this?

`\sin(2x+1)`

What is the "official" way to input trig functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\sin` does not expect an argument, thus curly argument braces do not make sense.

Since the precedence of the binary operator `+` in math is less high than a function argument, parentheses are required:

```
\sin(2x + 1)
```

And a little LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
  \exists x \in \mathbb{R}\colon \sin(2x + 1) \ne \sin 2x + 1
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: An argument! Thanks, that's the word I was looking for. Sorry, I'm very new to all this!

Comment: The best way to thank for an answer is to accept it (the check mark) and upvote it (the up arrow). You can upvote more than one answer.

Comment: Is it okay to personally thank someone even having accepted the answer? I feel very appreciative that Heiko spent so much effort answering my rather simple question without being condescending. (By the way, I couldn't mark it accepted so soon :) )

Comment: @SkeletonBow Thanks for the feedback. Now I know, that I have understood the question correctly and that there is no need for further refinements of the answer.